# Implementing setter and getter in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I want to implement setter and getter on local 
javascript variable. Here is an example function:

```
function someThing() {
   var someLocalvariable = '';
}

// with this function I want to 
// return value of someLocalvariable
// also if it is possible to implement
// setter in this way. 
someThing.prototype.getLocalVar = function() {

}
```

I want variable to be 'realy' private. I don't wont
to use something like this:
someThing.prototype.someLocalvariable =

or

```
function someThing() {
   this.someLocalvariable = '';
}
```

or attaching function inside someThing() like this:

```
function someThing() {
      var someLocalvariable = '';
   this.getLocalvariable = function() {
      return someLocalvariable;
   }
}
```

I would be very grateful for any guidance and assistance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your last example of what you don't want to do <s>won't work (it has syntax errors),</s> *(it's been fixed)* but I think you may have meant the usual way of doing this, which is to make the getter and setter closures within the constructor function (below).

Unfortunately, if you want truly private variables, this is just about your only option. There is no other way to get *truly* private, *instance-specific* variables. However, see "hack" below.

Here's the correct version of the usual way of doing this (which I think you said you don't want, but for completeness):

```
function SomeThing() {
    var privateVar;

    this.setPrivateVar = function(val) {
        privateVar = val;
    };
    this.getPrivateVar = function() {
        return privateVar;
    };
}

// use:
var t = new Something();
t.setPrivateVar("foo");
console.log(t.getPrivateVar()); // "foo"
```

Like most, I first read of this pattern on [Douglas Crockford's site](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

This option does carry a downside: Every instance created via the `SomeThing` constructor function gets its *own* two functions. They *cannot* be shared between instances. So if there are going to be hundreds or thousands of `SomeThing` instances in your app, that's something to be considered from a memory perspective. If there are going to be a couple of hundred or fewer, it probably doesn't matter. (Those numbers are pulled out of a hat and you should not trust them, you'll have to review your code's memory use when/if there's some kind of issue; but you get the idea.)

The hack: If your instances will already have some kind of unique identifier on them as public data (or you're willing to add one, again it will be public), and if you're willing to add a fair bit of complication into the use of the instances, you can have a private cache that holds the data for all of your instances that only your code can access, and key into that cache via the unique identifier of the object. Like this (in this example, I'm allocating the `id` values, but you can use existing unique IDs if you have them):

```
var SomeThing = (function() {
    var cache = {}, idAllocator = 0;

    function SomeThing() {
        this.id = ++idAllocator; // The unique identifier, can be a string if desired
        cache[this.id] = {};
    }
    SomeThing.prototype.getPrivateVar = function() {
        var data = cache[this.id];
        return data && data.privateVar;
    };
    SomeThing.prototype.setPrivateVar = function(value) {
        cache[this.id].privateVar = value;
    };
    SomeThing.prototype.destroy = function() {
        delete cache[this.id];
    };

    return SomeThing;
})();
```

Here's how that works: All of the functions are closures over the `cache` local variable in the outer scoping function. We index into that using the unique ID of the object, which gives us an object on which we put our private data members. When the code using the instance is done using it, that code *must* call `destroy` (which is a major downside to this pattern) so we remove the private data object from `cache` by deleting the property for our `id`.

Caveats and costs:

- You still have a public piece of data that is the key to your private data (`id` in the above)
- Users of the instances created by `SomeThing` **must** call `destroy` on those instances when they're done with them. This is anathema to the way JavaScript's garbage handling works, but it's a requirement of the pattern above because otherwise you end up with cruft building up in the `cache` object.
- (I wouldn't worry about this one) Eventually, if you're using the automatic `id` values above, you'll run out of them, if your app creates and destroys a *lot* of these instances. But JavaScript numbers go very high up indeed, and if that's an issue just find a different way to allocate IDs rather than the simplistic always-increasing system above.

I haven't had to use the pattern above in my work yet, but I expect there are use-cases for it involving thousands of `SomeThing` instances and thus the desire not to have per-instance functions.

---

Side note: In the above, I changed `someThing` to `SomeThing`. In JavaScript, the standard practice is for the names of normal functions to start with a lower-case letter, and for the names of constructor functions (ones you use with `new`) to start with a capital letter. Since `SomeThing` is meant to be used with `new`, I capped it. This is only convention, but it's an overwhelmingly popular one and, of course, it's used within the language definition itself (`Date` is a constructor, `setHours` is a function).

Comment: He already knows about this though since it's in one of his examples of what he doesn't want to do.

Comment: @Thor84no: The example you're talking about isn't actually the above, but I think you're right that it was meant to be. I've edited to address that.

Comment: The revised version is very thorough. Great answer.

Comment: @TJCrowder: I have heard the argument against the first (i.e. Crockford's) pattern regarding memory usage -- and I think it's plausible -- but never actually seen anyone post tests. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @FK82: No, I've never seen something going into profiling it. Note that it will be incredibly sensitive to the JavaScript engine used, possibly the size of the functions, etc. On a very smart engine, I'd expect the overhead to be minimal: Multiple function *objects* (which needn't be that expensive), but with shared underlying code. Less optimized engines may not reuse the code amongst different function objects (and the Function objects *have* to be different for the engine to be compliant with the spec; the underlying code is a different matter).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Good point. I was thinking the other way around actually. Meaning that the `Function`s specified in the prototype will have to be instantiated by the JavaScript engine -- when the parent `Function` is being instantiated -- anyway because they each open up an individual execution context. Dunno if that is in fact accurate or not but I imo it's likely the case.

Comment: @FK82: The `Function` objects assigned to a prototype are shared between instances. If you have a `Foo` constructor function, and you have a function assigned to `Foo.prototype.bar`, that **same** function is used by all instances created via `new Foo()`. There's only one `Function` object for `bar`. This is the key reason for having them on the prototype. In contrast, if you created a function *within* the call to `Foo` as in the Crockford pattern above, there will be a new function created every time you call `new Foo()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use Object.defineProperty() in the function constructor in order to define your getter and setter [more info here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)..

To make truly private (not visible to the outside) some values use a Closure, 
more info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

In the following example we define a getter and setter for property `temperature`, where the inner "private" value is stored in a variable `var temperature`.

`var temperature` will never be visible/accessibly from the outside of `Archiver()` has it is a Closure.

Please note that this pattern works on ES5 as Object.defineProperty() it is not supported on ES3.

```
function Archiver() {
    var temperature = null;
    var archive = [];

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'temperature', {
        get: function () {
            console.log('get!');
            return temperature;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            temperature = value;
            archive.push({ val: temperature });
        }
    });

    this.getArchive = function () {
        return archive;
    };
}

var arc = new Archiver();
arc.temperature; // 'get!'
arc.temperature = 11;
arc.temperature = 13;
arc.getArchive(); // [{ val: 11 }, { val: 13 }]
```

Comment: this would appear to be the best solution now that Object.DefineProperty exists, and allows you to use the getters/setters as if they were regular properties.

Comment: @sweaver2112 yes you can see browser compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
function Field(val){
    var value = val;

    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    };

    this.setValue = function(val){
        value = val;
    };
}
var field = new Field("test");
field.value
// => undefined
field.setValue("test2")
field.getValue()
```

Check ref: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Crockford has written [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) on implementing private members in JavaScript

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. If you have a local variable in someThing(), the function you attach to the prototype can't read its value (it's private, remember?). Your last example is the normal solution to this problem, why isn't this good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try these two ways to achieve setter and getter

```
var address = {

            street : "No street",
            city : "No city",
            state : "No state",     

            get getAddress()
            {
                return (this.street+","+this.city+","+this.state);
            },

            set setAddress(theAddress)
            {
                var part = theAddress.toString().split(", ");
                this.street = part[0] || "";
                this.city = part[1] || "";
                this.state = part[2] || "";
            }
        };


        address.setAddress = "27 Sus Road, Pune, MH";
        console.log(address.getAddress);


        //Other setter and getter

        function Square(side)
        {
            this._side = side;


        };

        Square.prototype = {

            set setSide(side){ 
                this._side = side;
            },

            get getSide(){ 
                return this._side;
            },

            get getArea(){ 
                return (this._side * this._side);
            }               
        };


        var mySquare = new Square(10);

        mySquare.setSide = 15;

        console.log("Area of square is "+mySquare.getArea+" with side "+mySquare.getSide);
```

Answer (score 0):

First method

```
var address = {

            street : "No street",
            city : "No city",
            state : "No state",     

            get getAddress()
            {
                return (this.street+","+this.city+","+this.state);
            },

            set setAddress(theAddress)
            {
                var part = theAddress.toString().split(", ");
                this.street = part[0] || "";
                this.city = part[1] || "";
                this.state = part[2] || "";
            }
        };


        address.setAddress = "27 Sus Road, Pune, MH";
        console.log(address.getAddress);
```

Second method

```
function Square(side)
        {
            this._side = side;


        };

        Square.prototype = {

            set setSide(side){ 
                this._side = side;
            },

            get getSide(){ 
                return this._side;
            },

            get getArea(){ 
                return (this._side * this._side);
            }               
        };


        var mySquare = new Square(10);

        mySquare.setSide = 15;

        console.log("Area of square is "+mySquare.getArea+" with side "+mySquare.getSide);
```